# How to check permission on custom setting from apex code

Tags: permissions, salesforce, apex-code, apex

In Apex, given a custom setting "ThisSetting" containing items "ThisSettingFirst", "ThisSettingSecond", "ThisSettingThird", how would I correctly code these if statements?

if (the-currently-logged-on-user-doesnt-have-permission-to-read-custom-settings)

if (the-currently-logged-on-user-doesnt-have-permission-to-update-custom-settings)

if (the-currently-logged-on-user-doesnt-have-permission-to-read-custom-setting-ThisSetting)

if (the-currently-logged-on-user-doesnt-have-permission-to-update-custom-setting-ThisSetting)

if (the-currently-logged-on-user-doesnt-have-permission-to-read-custom-setting-ThisSettingFirst)

if (the-currently-logged-on-user-doesnt-have-permission-to-update-custom-setting-ThisSettingFirst)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) Class methods to check permissions of current user for that particular object/setting.

```
Schema.sObjectType objType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('ThisSetting__c');
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objDesc = objType.getDescribe();

if(objDesc.isUpdateable()) {
    System.debug('Updateable');
}
if(objDesc.isCreateable()) {
    System.debug('Createable');
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Are permissions more granular than the setting name, i.e. are there settings for each value, or is it just the setting itself that has a permission?

Comment: Using Hierarchy Custom Setting, you can get record only for the specific user or profile or org. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm